# Orient two objects to face the same direction (Computer Visualization)

Tags: c++, computer-vision, vtk

I have two STL models of a scanned skull that are similar but not the same. When they are rendered side by side as actors in a vtkRenderer, they are facing different directions and one has been rotated 180 degrees.

Normally, I would just hard-code in the transformation so that they are both oriented facing the screen, but in this case, there will be lots of similar but different skulls uploaded, all of which might face different directions.

So, can anyone suggest a VTK specific way to *programmatically* orient the skulls so they both face they same direction? If not in a VTK specific way, does there exist a generally accepted method to do this else where in computer visualization software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you know rotation angles for each skull I would suggest to use that knowledge (eg.: prepare file with rotation angles for each model) and rotate them on load.

If not, then you have a real problem. If assumed that these skulls are pretty similar then I could suggest to try to align these skulls to each other, so in result they will be facing same direction.

You can achieve that through dedicated software like [Geomagic](https://www.3dsystems.com/software/geomagic-wrap), [CloudCompare](http://www.danielgm.net/cc/), or [MeshLab](http://www.meshlab.net/) , you can also write your own algorithm (Eg.: [Least Squares Matching](https://www.research-collection.ethz.ch/bitstream/handle/20.500.11850/67181/eth-28371-01.pdf?sequence=1)). You can also try to use library with already implemented alignment algorithms like [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/)

Manual approach: You can use 3 points alignment method to achieve that. It will be way faster than trying doing that through rotations and translations. ([How it works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygRm52WnNT8))